# XML Traffic Copping

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have an "xml-source" that is sending me XML.

The xml can come in two ways.  One that is "Order" related.  A second that is "Employee" related.

Typically, when I shred xml, I use some Linq-To-Xml to parse a known xml-schema.

But now, with 2 different xml-schema's coming at me, I am trying to find the most efficient way to "traffic cop" the Xml.

What I've tried is:

1. Parse "version1".........and then check for mandatory (order) data (like valid OrderId's).  If that data isn't there, then:
2. Parse for "version2"........then check for mandatory employee data, like employeeSSN.
3. If both fail, then I log that I didn't get either.

Any ideas on what is the most efficient way to do this traffic copping of the Xml?

My other idea is the create xsd's, and validate.  But then I'm running a xsd-validate....and then sending it to a "parser".....so that may be less efficient than the idea above...of try1, try2, then fail.

While I can choose when I traffic-cop the xml, I cannot change the way the xml is sent to me.  The xml is put on a queue, and the architecture does not allow for putting different xml's on different queues.....via contract with the third party vendor.

Any idea that I'm not seeing?

I don't like different xml's on the same queue............but that's ship has sailed.

The xml's below are made up........but show that the xml's are just completely different and share nothing.

```
<root>
    <orders>
        <order orderId="ABC123">
            <orderDetails>
                <orderDetail itemName="Bike" quantity="1"/>
                <orderDetail itemName="TeddyBear" quantity="2"/>
                <orderDetail itemName="Doll" quantity="3"/>
            </orderDetails>
        </order>
        <!--  -->
        <order orderId="DEF234">
            <orderDetails>

                <orderDetail itemName="Truck" quantity="4"/>
                <orderDetail itemName="Marbles" quantity="5"/>
                <orderDetail itemName="BoardGame" quantity="6"/>

            </orderDetails>
        </order>
    </orders>
</root>




<root>
    <employees>
        <employee employeeSSN="222222222" firstName="John">
            <employeeEmails>
                <employeeEmail emailValue="john@home.com" />
                <employeeEmail emailValue="john@work.com" />
            </employeeEmails>
        </employee>
        <!--  -->
        <employee employeeSSN="3333333" firstName="Mary">
            <employeeEmails>

                <employeeEmail emailValue="mary@home.com" />
                <employeeEmail emailValue="mary@work.com" />
                <employeeEmail emailValue="mary@spamcatcher.com" />

            </employeeEmails>
        </employee>
    </employees>
</root>
```

Comment: If the schemas never change, just keep doing what you're doing. Search for an "employees" element or "orders" element and go from there

Comment: Ok.  I figured there wasn't anything else..but figured I'd ask the gurus out there.

Comment: I think checking them against an XSD would be the "right" way to do this and would allow you to generically extend this process to a multitude of formats. But if there is a simple, surefire way to distinguish them, and extensibility isn't a concern, then I agree that the simple option is probably the way to go.